# Set variable without default datatype

Tags: python

I am creating a function to parse a page with selenium

```
def get_position_links(start_url, browser):
    """
    Retrieve the position_links 
    """
    position_links = []
    next_page_element = ""
    next_page_attribute = ""

    #kick off
    browser.get(start_url)

    def get_position_links_and_next_page_elememnt_in_the_current_page(position_links):
        ##Get the position_links within the page
        #browser change appropriately with the page change
        nonlocal  next_page_element
        nonlocal  next_page_attribute
        position_elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("position_link")  # Retrieve the postions link elements
        #select those only contain python in the title
        position_elements = [p for p in position_elements if "python" in p.text.lower()]
        #position_links as global variable set at the top
        position_links.extend([p.get_attribute("href") for p in position_elements])

        #nonlocal to avoied repeated return
        next_page_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("pager_next")
        #next_page_attribute for the while flag.
        next_page_attribute = next_page_element.get_attribute("class").strip()

    #handle the start_url
    get_position_links_and_next_page_elememnt_in_the_current_page()

    #Traverse until there's no next pages.
    while not next_page_attribute.endswith("disabled"):
        # time.sleep(random.uniform(1,20))
        next_page_element.click()
        get_position_links_and_next_page_elememnt_in_the_current_page()

    return position_links
```

In the enclosing function I declareed  `next_page_element = ""` `next_page_attribute = ""` which I am not sure their data type.

However, I should set a data type for them randomly,
How could I set a variable without default data type like

```
var nextPageElement
var nextPageAttribute
```

in Javascript?

Comment: Why does the data type matter?

Comment: so, what I am doing is a accepted practice?  @Aran-Fey

Comment: I think you need to show what you are doing with those variables inside the nested function.

Comment: I posted it @DanielRoseman

Comment: Python doesn't really have static data types, so you could assign `next_page_element=True` and `next_page_attribute=17` without causing trouble.

Comment: In Python, you just assign to variables whenever you need them. There are no variable declarations, and variables aren't typed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any reason to use nonlocal variables here at all. You should just return the values from the function.

```
def get_position_links_and_next_page_elememnt_in_the_current_page(position_links):
    ...
    return next_page_element, next_page_attribute 

next_page_element, next_page_attribute = get_position_links_and_next_page_elememnt_in_the_current_page(position_links)
```

Now you don't need nonlocal, you don't need to predefine the elements, and you don't even really need a nested function.

Comment: I wonder it could be better to abstract my code use a function rather many comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to find the data type of the variable.

> type()

For example,

```
a = 1.0
print(type(a))
```

> `Output: <class 'float'>`

Explicit data type conversion is called 'Typecasting'

The general form of explicit data type conversion is

```
> (required_data_type)(expression)
```

you can dig into some of the commonly used explicit data type conversions.

links: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-data-type-conversion